# Select the same class in some pages

Tags: css

I need to select the `targetDiv` class in only some of my pages using only CSS.

I'm currently using the following, is there any way to write this CSS shorter?

```
.page-id-1 .targetDiv, .page-id-3 .targetDiv, .page-id-5 .targetDiv, .page-id-7 .targetDiv 
{ display:none;}
```

Comment: With pure CSS there is no other/shorter way when HTML markup stay unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a common class between those pages, other than that there's no other way if HTML markup stay unchanged.

Also, if you are using SCSS, you may write this way:

```
.page-id-1, .page-id-3, .page-id-5, .page-id-7 {
  .targetDiv {
    display: none;
  }
}
```